# Make table of the following format

Tags: tables

How can I make a table that has rows that look like this:

[image]

There will be a handful more rows with the same formatting.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this. To use Helvetica, which should be installed on your computer, you need to add the `fontspec` package and compile your `.tex` file with `lualatex` or `xelatex` engines. More final touches are required after you finish typing your information accurately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Helvetica LT Std}
\usepackage{xcolor,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\color{black!90}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
2014 & \textbf{Data Systems Engineer} \hfill \textcolor{gray}{LBNL, Berkly}\\
     & Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text \\ 
%
2013 & \textbf{Data Systems Engineer} \hfill \textcolor{gray}{LBNL, Berkly}\\
     & Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text Running climate models ... and continuous text \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]